# Converting '4 days ago' etc. to the actual dates

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, time, countdown

I have a massive spreadsheet in which all dates are written this way:

```
2 days ago 
9 days ago
34 days ago
54 days ago
etc.
```

Is there a clever Python way to convert these data to the actual dates, if I tell Python what date '1 day ago' is?

Comment: I'd probably approach it like: extract an integer from the string somehow, then put it in a `datetime.timedelta`, which you then subtract from today's date.

Comment: Why the downvotes? I did a search and could not find a similar question anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#timedelta-objects).

Extract the value from that string in your spreadsheet and then use

```
d = date.today() - timedelta(days_to_subtract)
```

Answer (score 3):

If the input date format may slightly vary (human input) then you could use [`parsedatetime` module](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime) to parse human-readable date/time text into `datetime` objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from datetime import datetime
import parsedatetime  # $ pip install parsedatetime

now = datetime(2015, 3, 8) # the reference date
cal = parsedatetime.Calendar()
for line in sys.stdin: # at most one date per line
    dt, type = cal.parseDT(line, now)
    if type > 0:
        print(dt)
```

#### Output

```
2015-03-06 00:00:00
2015-02-27 00:00:00
2015-02-02 00:00:00
2015-01-13 00:00:00
```