# Converting dates for comparison with python

Tags: python, date, web-scraping, type-conversion, comparison

I have a web scraping problem that I just can't get any further with.

I want to filter out data from a website that publishes new information every day.
The website supplies the date on which the information was published as a string in the format DD.MM.YYYY, e.g. '31.12.2022'

My script should run every day and then filter out the dates where the publication date is exactly 4 days earlier than the current date "tagesdatum = datetime.date.today()".
Example: tagesdatum = 23.02.2023 --> data from 16.02.2023 are filtered.

I am failing at the conversions of the date types to be able to do the comparison. I don't understand the documentation for datetime at this point.

Does anyone have a specific tip for me?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting '4 days ago' etc. to the actual dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833471/converting-4-days-ago-etc-to-the-actual-dates)

Comment: Not complete. 
In order to subtract the days from the current date in the first step, the link actually helps me a lot.

But, I have different date types. One is the date of the website as a string and the other is the current date from today(). It's not clear to me how I can manage the comparison here if I want to compare many dates.